# How To Adding/Removing Class on Resize the Screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to use .titleClickHide and .titleClick classes only on mobile views.
They will not able to used on large views.What should i change or add to my code?

```
 $(window).resize(function () {
        console.log('screen changed');

        if (screen.width > 760) {
            $('#footerMenu').find('.li').removeClass("titleClickHide").removeClass('titleClick');
        }
        else {
            $(".footerMenuTitle .li").first().addClass("titleClick");
            $('.titleClick').click(function () {
                if ($(this).parents('ul').find('li.show').length > 1) {
                    $('.titleClickHide').hide().removeClass('show');
                } else {
                    $('.titleClickHide').hide().removeClass('show');
                    $(this).parents('ul').find('li').show().addClass('show');
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: using `@media` in css is a way better .. but if you need to use js always don't use events inside `.reize` But use the `if` statement for screen size inside the click event not outside it

Comment: read about media breakpoints here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, take the click function out of the resize function.

Second, if you want to remove several classes using the removeClass() method, consolidate them as

**$( ".class or #id" ).removeClass( "myClass yourClass" )**

Refer to https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    console.log('screen changed');
    if (screen.width > 760) {
        $('#footerMenu').find('.li').removeClass("titleClickHide titleClick");
    } else {
        $(".footerMenuTitle .li").first().addClass("titleClick");
    }
    });

$('.titleClick').click(function () {
    if ($(this).parents('ul').find('li.show').length > 1) {
        $('.titleClickHide').hide().removeClass('show');
    } else {
        $('.titleClickHide').hide().removeClass('show');
        $(this).parents('ul').find('li').show().addClass('show');
    }
});
```

After you make the changes, check the console and see if there is any errors and what else you may see when testing.

And it is highly recommended to use CSS @media instead of resize() method. Resize() would slow down website performance when resizing due to the fact the function triggers at every single pixel change. For example, resizing from 768px width down to 500px, the function triggers 268 times.

Comment: Thanks a lot. @Sam

Comment: No problem. I am glad to help.